# Iterate over a list to create functions

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I am trying to solve a large system of differential equations using `solve_ivp`.

```
from scipy import integrate
sol = integrate.solve_ivp(func_system, (0,100), initial_value_array, t_eval)
```

The `func_system` is a system of differential equations that depends on the length of the list `X`:

```
X = ['a','b','c','d',...]

K1, K2, K3, K4 = [1, 2, 2, 1]

def dadt(X,t):
    return -K1*X[0]+K2*X[1]
def dbdt(X,t):
    return K2*X[0]-(K2+K3+K4)*X[1]
def dcdt (X,t):
    return ....
def dddt (X,t):
    return ....
```

and so on.

```
def func_system(X,t):
    return np.array([dadt(X,t), dbdt(X,t), dcdt(X,t), dddt(X,t)])
```

Because X can be very long, I'd like to iterate over the list to create function names. For example,

```
dxdt = ['d'+a+'dt' for a in X]

for i in range(len(dxdt)):
    def dxdt[i]:
        return something
```

, where I'd get "something" from a dataframe. My question is is it possible to iterate over a list to create function names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct 17 2019, 06:42:36) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: X = ['a','b','c','d']                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [2]: K1, K2, K3, K4 = [1, 2, 2, 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [3]: code = ['def d{symbol}dt(X, t): return "something"'.format(symbol=symbol) for symbol in X]                                                                                                                                         

In [4]: functions = {}                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [5]: for func in code: 
   ...:     exec(func, {}, functions) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [6]: functions                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[6]: 
{'dadt': <function dadt(X, t)>,
 'dbdt': <function dbdt(X, t)>,
 'dcdt': <function dcdt(X, t)>,
 'dddt': <function dddt(X, t)>}

In [7]: functions['dadt'](1, 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[7]: 'something'
```

Comment: Writing code as string is pretty bad in a sense that it's hard to detect any bugs in it, as 
syntactic analysis bypasses such strings. It is basically the same as using eval, for which there are lots of good posts why you should not use it. However, as function names can be used as vars, it is easy to just define those functions and then call them in a chain using similar loop.

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested, you can simply use eg. dict to accomplish this. Not the most elegant solution, but definitely doable and not that ugly even, if all functions *share the same signature*:

```py
dispatch = {
  'dadt': lambda X, t: -K1*X[0]+K2*X[1],
  'dbdt': lambda X, t: K2*X[0]-(K2+K3+K4)*X[1],
  # you get the idea
}

# later, eg. to call dadt(my_vector, t):
rval = dispatch["dadt"](my_vector, t)

# or, if you want to have pretty functions eg. that you call often, functions
# are just values too:

dadt = dispatch["dadt"]
dadt(my_vector, t)
```

Comment: personally I would use lambdas, however I think the exec shows that true functions can be created dynamically in code.

Comment: That's usually quite bad idea, tried to explain why :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `dict`? The keys would be the names and the values functions.

Comment: Oh come on! I am trying now for like 10 minutes to change the __name__ attribute of a function object. I was so close! But yes... You are probably right :(

Comment: I think you mean "values functions", my answer is probably what you were suggesting